# Spanning navigation bar CSS

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having trouble getting my navigation bar to span the width of the page and to locate itself underneath the header I've added. Could someone please help me?

```
<body>
<div id= "header">
  FOOD
</div>

<div id= "navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Favs </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cusine </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Asian </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Europe </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Recipes </a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
 </body>
```

This is the css I've used. I kept adding widths but it just seems to have different widths.

```
#navbar
{
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 z-index: 1000; 
 position: relative; 
 top: 100px; 
 }

#navbar ul
{
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 right: 50%;
 }

 #navbar ul li
 {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 }

 #navbar ul li a 
 {
 display: block;
 margin: 0px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #735D41;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid;
 width: 100%;
 }

 #navbar ul li ul li a
 {
 background-color: #735D41;
 color: white;
 }

#navbar ul ul 
{
display: none; 
position: relative;
left: 0px;
right: auto;
}

#navbar ul ul li 
{
left: auto;
margin: 0px;
clear: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you include a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry @Marcatectura. I don't have one yet but I'm sigining up soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good option would be to remove most of your floats and relative positioning and instead use `display:table` on the `ul` and `display:table-cell` on the `li`s. This will enable you to stretch the nav across the screen. Try it with this:

```
#navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
 }

 #navbar ul li {
    display:table-cell;
 }
```

[**See an Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCHD6/)

In this example I used your code but changed and removed a few things. It should be sufficient enough to give you a good idea of what to do.

Comment: Thanks @Mark M. I'll check it out right now. Sorry I couldn't up vote the answer, I don't have enough rep.